# Button with absolute position doesn't stretch to full width

Tags: html, css, css-position

Button element doesn't stretch to full parent width with left/right zero technique. It perfectly works for `a` tag but not for `button`. What am I missing?

The question is why left/right approach isn't working for button.
I know that I can use wrapper, `calc()` or flexbox. But it seems strange that old way doesn't work.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rtnj8rL/25/)

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

a.button {
  top: 0;
}

button.button {
  top: 20px;
  display: block;
}

button.button-full {
  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="button">Link button</a>
  <button class="button">Button button</button>
  <button class="button button-full">Button button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just do; `width: 100%`?

Comment: According to @giorgio, width: 100% works

Comment: width: 100% lacks when parent have paddings

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to show the padding part?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: The updated fiddle has your button with `left: 20px;`. Setting this to `0px` fixes it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rtnj8rL/44/)

Comment: @rideron89 Nope, It just set button size off paddings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `width:inherit` on the `button`, but be aware that it won't work when `box-sizing:border-box` is set on the container, otherwise you will probably need `width:calc(100% - paddings)`, also mentioned in the other answer.

```
button {
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you also know why button has different sizing rules?

Comment: See this answer for the reasons https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293542/483779

Answer (score 0):

you can add button width to 100% so that it will be 100% of its parent container.

```
 .button {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   **width: 100%;**

   background: green;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: width: 100% lacks when parent have paddings

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: calc();` to the `.button` as in

```
a.button {
  top: 0;
  width: calc();
}
```

This will stretch it to 100% and retain your padding of the parent element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but calc works slower, has worse browser compatibility and a little bit dirtier.

Comment: Slower, like 0.000000000000000000000001 miliseconds slower

Answer (score 0):

Your button is overflowing the parent since your button is `absolute` and has left of `20px`.

**There is no need to compensate for the parent padding.**

Change left `left: 0px;` or remove `position: absolute;`.

```
.button{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  ...
}
```

I would rather be removing `position: absolute`;